# Como converter inteiro para um array de char ou um array de inteiros

Tags: java

```
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = key.nextInt();
```

Supondo que num seja 100, como converter num para um array de char onde:

```
char[0] == '1'
char[1] == '0'
char[2] == '0'
```

Ou converter para um array de inteiros onde:

```
int[0] == 1
int[1] == 0
int[2] == 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso em diversos modos, o mais simples seria converter o seu numero para uma String e depois aplicar o método `toCharArray`, exemplo:

```
int num = 100; // Seu numero
String numStr = Integer.toString(num); // Converte o mesmo em uma String
char numArr[] = numStr.toCharArray(); // Converte a String em um Array de chars
```

Se você gostaria de ter um Array de inteiros, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
int arrInt[] = numStr.chars().map(c -> Character.getNumericValue((char)c)).toArray();
```

`chars()` irá retornar um `IntStream` que pode ser iterável através do metódo `map()` e dentro deste nós convertemos novamente cada valor caractere da String em um inteiro aplicando o metódo `getNumericValue`, uma vez terminada a iteração, o metódo `toArray` é chamado para converter a stream um array, que no seu caso será um array de inteiros.